# How to write a power function for big numbers in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose I want to calculate **2^10000** using *Math.pow()*. For which my code is-

```
long num = (long)Math.pow(2, 10000);
System.out.println(num);
```

Here I'm getting output as **9223372036854775807** which I guess is the limit of long. But if I write like this-

```
double n = Math.pow(2, 10000);
System.out.println(n);
```

the o/p is *Infinity* which is a bit weird. Anyone please help me with this.

Comment: The answer is around 2 x 10 ^ 3010 and Java's double maxes out at around 2^1023 so "infinity" is the right answer.

Comment: Infinity is indeed a silly choice as a result considering that the value is "nowhere near infinity" :) , but that's what we have to live with. For large numbers it's always better to use BigInteger and BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, but be aware that `BigInteger` is not very efficient and I don't consider it suitable for production work for math problems.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  BigInteger two = new BigInteger( "2" );
  BigInteger twoToTenThousand = two.pow( 10000 );
  System.out.println( twoToTenThousand );
}
```

Comment: Is there a suitable alternative to `BigDecimal` if you need to do production work with big numbers?  Or is it just a case of grit your teeth, say "I gotta do what I gotta do", and use `BigDecimal` anyway?

Comment: I'd say the right thing to do is to use `double`.  If it overflows, then your problem setup was unreasonable.  You have to be very careful with `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` or you'll shoot yourself in the foot on full auto.  As long as you understand them and test thoroughly they're useful, but they're not some kind of magic bullet.

Comment: For comparison: "it is estimated that the there are between 10^78 to 10^82 atoms in the known, observable universe." (According to Google.) Consider that `double`'s limit is (in base 10) around 9 x 10^301.  If you need larger numbers than that, you're probably misunderstanding something seriously about your problem set up.

Answer (score 0):

2^10000 overflows the limit of both longs and doubles. However, in Java, overflowing in longs and doubles are treated differently. If you add 1 to the largest possible value in a long, you wrap around and the result is the smallest possible value for a long, equal to -2^63. On the other hand, if you add 1 to the largest possible value in a double, you get Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html for more information.